# 404 when using named placeholders for variable parts of Panels path

Tags: views, panels, 7, path-aliases

I'm creating a landing page using a custom content type in Drupal 7, I've set up the views and had everything working correctly, but then I decided to change something at the last minute and add named placeholders to my URL. For some reason I'm receiving a 404 when calling the specific URL.  Do I have to do anything specific to my contextual filters in views or in Contexts, so that the URL actually works?

I have this set for my landing page /publications/magazine/2014/SPRING (/Publications/Magazine/%field_year/%mag_issue)
I have a custom date format set to year only for the date field and have a taxonomy vocabulary called seasons (fall, winter, spring summer)

For my contextual filter, I have Content: Has taxonomy term ID using Raw Value with the specific vocabulary set, one of my views requires this. That's really the only unique thing here. I'm working locally at the moment, so i dont have a url, but any suggestions would be helpful, spending 3 hours so far trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others who find this question and have similar scenario make sure for your arguments you set your context up properly, for mine I had context set to Taxonomy term ID, instead of the Name and as soon as I changed it to name and saved it. Cleared Cache, everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

One additional thing to add is that even if you're not planning on loading a context with the placeholder, you still need to set it to *something* in the Arguments tab in Page Manager.

---

For example, if you just want to pipe it straight into a Views contextual filter in a Views Content Pane:

1. In the Page Manager 'Arguments' tab, set it to "String"
2. In the Views settings page for the Content Pane display of your view, under Argument Input, choose "From Panel Argument"

It'll then stop throwing a 404 error and will pipe the string through to the view as intended.